# "synergy system tray is unavailable,quiting"

Tags: synergy

Recnetly,I install synergy(1.4.8) to my linux(ubuntu-11.10) computer,when I running it,there is a warning "synergy system tray is unavailable,quiting".I'm firt install it and I don't know waht happened,somebody help me?thank you.

Comment: I install synergy1.4.8

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you start it up before the systray has had a chance to initialize. Just move it to later in your configuration, or put a sleep in your startup script to wait a couple of seconds before trying to start.

Also I hate this trouble when using Cairo Dock because I didn't have a system tray turned on. So make sure that's not you too.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

*is easy to out!!!*

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4224/synergy-system-tray-is-unavailable-quitting