# XMonad + Synergy: System tray is unavailable, quitting

Tags: synergy, xmonad

I'm trying to use [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) with my [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) setup.

When I try to start synergy it pops up an error message saying:

> System tray is unavailable, quitting

- I'm on Ubuntu server 13.10
- I don't have any sort of system tray
- [this](https://superuser.com/questions/461991/synergy-system-tray-is-unavailable-quiting) is the only relevant question I could find, but it did not help me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

XMonad doesn't provide any system tray facility so for apps that require one you will need to install a system tray app like Trayer and add that to your .xSession or similar startup file. There are a lots of examples of how to set up a tray with XMonad, usually with some sort of panel. I use XMonad.Layout.Monitor to float a transparent xclock and tray in the top right corner of my screen. Note that I have used a fixed position and size for simplicity, you may want something more dynamic.

```
 trayer = monitor {
     prop = ClassName "trayer"
   , rect = Rectangle (1920-150) 0 100 16
     -- avoid flickering
   , persistent = True
     -- make the window transparent
   , opacity = 0.6
     -- assign it a name to be able to toggle it independently of others
   , name = "trayer"
   }
clock = monitor {
     prop = Title "clock"
   , rect = Rectangle (1920-50) 0 50 16
     -- avoid flickering
   , persistent = True
     -- make the window transparent
   , opacity = 0.6
     -- assign it a name to be able to toggle it independently of others
   , name = "clock"
   }
myLayout = ModifiedLayout trayer $ ModifiedLayout clock $ layoutHook defaultConfig
```